# What fairytale provided Big Jack Horner's staff?

Tags: weapon, object-identification, puss-in-boots-the-last-wish

All of Big Jack Horner's tools are explicit references to fairytales, or at the very least famous children's stories/movies. The hand that turns people to gold is from the story of King Midas, the "Eat Me" cookie is from Alice in Wonderland, the magic ball he looks into is The Wizard of Oz, even the bag he uses to hold everything is lifted from Marry Poppins.

The only thing I can't place, and haven't seen anybody else place, is the staff he uses in the final battle on top of The Wishing Star, pictured in a promo shot below:

[image]

It's a staff that looks to be made of wood with a magical sphere on top of it that appears to only shoot concussive blasts, so nothing specific enough to have a specific fairytale power. The closest thing anybody I've asked has come up with is that it might be Loki's staff from The Avengers, but that doesn't fit the common theme of influential children's stories/movies from roughly around the 1940's - 90's. And there's no shortage of staves in D&D/Fantasy that could be a perfect visual match.

Interestingly enough, that staff might have had a different design in the original draft of the character, but it still doesn't ring any bells for me personally.

[image]
[image]

Comment: [TV Tropes reckons](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/ShoutOut/PussInBootsTheLastWish) it's a reference to Gandalf's staff in the *Lord of the Rings* films, but I'm hesitant to make that an answer as it's very much a second-hand source.

Comment: The one from *Onward* looks quite similar; https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/HAsAAOSwW5JexNWH/s-l500.jpg

Comment: Does there need to be one? Jack had several items that are not linked to one story (e.g. unicorn horns, phoenix).